# Why is ipython returning NameError while decorating interact?

Tags: python-3.x, interactive, jupyter-lab, nameerror, sage

I was assigned to use `@interact` in a Sage project. The code provided in the class notes is:

```
@interact
def show_crank(angle = slider(0,2*pi,pi/20,pi/10,label='angle')):
    center = (0,0)
    endpnt = (cos(angle),sin(angle))
    pltcnt = point(center, size = 50)
    pltend = point(endpnt, size = 50)
    crank = line([center,endpnt])
    (pltcnt + crank + pltend).show(xmin=-1,xmax=1,ymin=-1,ymax=1)
```

However, when I attempt to run this,

`NameError: name 'interact' is not defined`

is returned. I'm currently using Jupyter Lab. Using the Python 3 or Sage kernels results in the same issue.

I've read articles SO suggested to me, though no solution jumped out at me. Here are the articles for posterity:

- [NameError (from a function) while using iPython Notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36142322/nameerror-from-a-function-while-using-ipython-notebook)
- [Ipython notebook : Name error for Imported script function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24778375/ipython-notebook-name-error-for-imported-script-function?rq=1)
- [Functions NameError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30382805/functions-nameerror?rq=1)
- [Python NameError: name is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14804084/python-nameerror-name-is-not-defined?rq=1)
- [NameErrors and functions in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29447713/nameerrors-and-functions-in-python?rq=1)

Comment: You need to import `interact` before you can use it - did your class notes really not mention that?

Comment: @jasonharper I figured as much. My professor uses CoCalc, not Jupyter Lab. I found an answer here: https://towardsdatascience.com/interactive-controls-for-jupyter-notebooks-f5c94829aee6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Make sure `ipywidgets` is installed.
- Activate widgets with: `jupyter nbextension enable --py widgetsnbextension`
- For Jupyter Lab use: `jupyter labextension install @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager`
- Finally: `import ipywidgets as widgets` and
  `from ipywidgets import *`

This solves one part of the problem, but not another one that arose.

`def show_crank(angle = slider(0,2*pi,pi/20,pi/10,label='angle')):`

prompts the NameError: `name 'slider' is not defined`. When using Jupyter Lab, the correct function call is `FloatSlider`.

EDIT: Credit for this goes to [Will Koehrsen](https://towardsdatascience.com/interactive-controls-for-jupyter-notebooks-f5c94829aee6).